# How to see history of files in VS code IDE?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, ide

Can you please help me to history of files like we see in other IDE's?

Am not getting the same in VS code editor ?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history

Answer (score 2):

[Click here to see the image of VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWV5L.png)
There is an option "Open recent" in "File".

Comment: I've just upvoted your answer, but most people might want to see `File -> Open Recent -> More... (Ctrl +R)` in your answer. As you know, it will show the whole list of file history.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to watch any file change over time is to install [git](https://git-scm.com/). In this way, you can review all the changes you have made to a file.

[preview file history on version control system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nPco.png)

If your project does not have a git service, you can review past changes using the [TIMELINE](https://www.amitmerchant.com/vs-code-timeline-your-local-version-control-system) feature in VSCode.

[preview file history on VSCode Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMXd3.png)